# File input label Blade

Tags: file, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a form with a file input field, I created a label for the input and made the input display none. and whenever I upload pictures it automatically submits the form. But the problem is it return the wrong ID with the link if I submit like this, if I just have a normal submit buttons it works.

```
@foreach($wedstrijden as $wedstrijd)

<a class="verslag-manager-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#verslagModal{{ $wedstrijd->id }}" href="">
  <p>Verslag </p>
</a>

--modal #verslagModal{{ $wedstrijd->id }}
<form action="/manager/fotos/upload/{{ $wedstrijd->id }}" class="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label class="btn btn-default btn-success" for="my-file-selector">
        <input onchange="this.form.submit()" id="my-file-selector" multiple name="sourceImage[]" type="file" style="display:none;">
        Upload Foto
    </label>

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <input style="display: none" type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submitBtn">

</form>
--modal
@endoforeach
```

In my route file I have the following route

```
Route::post('manager/fotos/upload/{id}', 'managerController@postFotoUpload');
```

But in my controller it always returns the latest id.

if I inspect my code in the browser the form url shows `/manager/fotos/upload/16` but if I dump the `$id` in my controller it return 17.

```
public function postFotoUpload($id, Request $request)
{
    foreach($request->file('sourceImage') as $foto)
    {
        $file = $foto;
        $destinationPath = 'img/' . $id . '/';
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

        $foto = new Foto();
        $foto->wedstrijd_id = $id;
        $foto->foto = $filename;
        $foto->save();


    }

    Session::flash('upload', true);

    Return Redirect::to('/manager');

}
```

Comment: You want to change the form behaviour or get right id ? What is the exact goal ?

Comment: I want to get the right id, but when I change my form ( without auto submit ) I get the right id, But I want it to auto submit and still give me the right id

Comment: From your code, it seems you have iterate your form in `foreach` Why do you want such many forms in your page  ?

Comment: That code was a bit wrong, I have a list with multiple matches and each match has its own button to open a modal with the form in it.

Comment: You consider each matches as each form ? If so those each form has the button inside the `</form>` ?

Comment: I updated my code maybe it is more clear now